# Поиск слова по первой букве java

Tags: java

Есть ли в java возможность по первой букве находить из массива/текстового документа слово? К примеру , в текстовом документе есть слова

```
Дом
Арбуз 
Питер
Польша
Привет
```

С клавиатуры вводят "п" , а программа выдаёт рандомное слово на букву П , к примеру "Питер".

Искал в интернете, но кроме подсчета слов и замены ничего найти не смог

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не надо искать в интернете, попробуйте просто выучить язык

```
String getFirstThatStartsWith(String s) {
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.startsWith(s))
            return word;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Слово не найдено");
}
```

или

```
String word = Arrays.stream(words)
                    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("п"))
                    .findAny()
                    .get();
```

Comment: Я бы хранил слова в мапе `Map<Char, List<String>>`. Тогда будет проще рандомно выбирать слово из листа: `String randomWord = map.get('п').get(randomIndex)`